# Laravel Can't Connect to database - Migrations - Error 2002

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, mamp, laravel-artisan

I have searched for a couple of hours now, and still am unable to find this.

I get 2 errors, if I use the database host as `'localhost'`, I get this error:

```
[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

and if I change the database host to `'127.0.0.1'` I get this error:

```
 [PDOException]                             
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Things I have tried:

- changing where the apache / mysql server is run (either user or `josh (Apache) / josh (MySQL)
- changing the port that MySQL runs on in MAMP, and putting that port in the mysql array in the `database.php` file
- changing the host of the connection from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and back.
- creating a new user in `phpmyadmin`
- turning off the firewall

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, add this after the `'host' => '127.0.0.1'`:

```
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

So the connection would look like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'        => 'mysql',
        'host'          => '127.0.0.1',
        'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'database'      => 'dbname',
        'username'      => 'josh',
        'password'      => 'pass',
        'charset'       => 'utf8',
        'collation'     => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'        => '',
    )
```

Comment: This works for me but it would be nice if someone could explain why this was needed?

Comment: Works for me too! thanks. but i don't know why we have to add this. I checked php.ini and the default unix_socket it's the same as this one that we set.

Comment: @KevinJung just make sure to take it out when deploying on the server

Comment: Wow this had me befuzzled. Thanks

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this for an hour. When I saw this i thought, surely not... Then it worked. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

fist clear your config file by typing

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then modify your `.env` file

```
APP_URL = 127.0.0.1
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

### IF you use lampp . You can try this:

> Open file mysql config. (you can open lampp control panel in /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run,after that open Configure of Mysql Database or open /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf).
>
> Find and see "socket       =/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock",
>
> Add 'unix_socket'      => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' to file database.php in laravel:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'unix_socket'      => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'luanvan'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'huuthang'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123456'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

> File mysql.sock depend on your install location of lampp. I let you see if you can't find it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following in ubuntu 15.10

```
copy the file or file contents from /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf to /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then open database.php file in your app/config folder and add the following line below 'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost')

```
'unix_socket' => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

That solved my problem, could save someone else's. Please note that it is VERY IMPORTANT you first verify the directory which contains mysql.sock file before configuring the path.