# I'm getting laravel mysql [2002] connection error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting an error `mysql connection [2002] error`. I have configured the `.env` file correctly. I'm using `xampp`. I also have other laravel apps on the same localhost, they're working correctly but this one isn't.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=satrap7
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Try changing `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost`

Comment: You can refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693933/laravel-cant-connect-to-database-migrations-error-2002

Comment: After change of `.env` edit, You need to clear the configuration cache using this  command: `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not set an **DB_PASSWORD**. Please grant permission for an user to **satrap7** database with a password and set this to your .env file. Or ( which I do not recommend ) but for local running db should be fine set your mysql root password and set this password in your .env